# What is the best way to restrict network access for one machine on a home LAN?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, firewall, rules

As an example, I have 3 computers on a home network:
Machine A
Machine B
Machine C

What I would like to do is isolate "Machine C", so that it cannot communicate with "A" or "B" and vice versa.  It should be an entirely separate entity.

Let's say I'm using a Linksys E4200.  Is there a good way to configure the above scenario with the default firmware?  Is it possible with non-default firmware such as DD-WRT or Tomato?  I do not have experience with this but have no problem learning.

My understanding is that this can be done by placing "Machine C" in the DMZ.  Unfortunately, I am told a lot of home routers do not have a secure way of setting up DMZ by default.  The two routers solution can work but still requires restricting administrative access from "Machine C" and adds an additional potential point of failure.

### **EDIT:**

From the sound of things, to have proper firewall rules in place I need an additional router.

Comment: What type of OS is machine C running?

Comment: Machine C will run Ubuntu

Comment: For home use the only thing is using hosts files. Otherwise you need a domain controller if using windows and complex dns rules. Placing a the machine in DMZ does not block anything. It allows ALL wan traffic. There is no easy way unless you use another router on a separate IP range that piggy backs on the default gateway.

Comment: I don't mind if Machine C is compromised, I accept that risk.  The intent is to ensure that Machine A and Machine B are protected from a compromised Machine C.  As per the other answer I think firewall rules may be the way to go, and I'll investigate subnetting for my router.

Comment: The advice you heard about the DMZ is more for commercial-grade networks. A real DMZ is separated from the network by a firewall; a home router's DMZ Host is just the default port forward target.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I had a feeling that the DMZ route wouldn't work for a typical home router.  So in commercial DMZs is there a physical appliance that serves as the firewall?  Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @rakemanyohneth yes, you have another router that's a firewall, creating a pocket between the two firewalls, called a DMZ.

Comment: Yeah. More professional-grade network setups tend to have a separate computer serving as a router and firewall; it connects to multiple networks, and regulates what traffic flows between them. A DMZ there could either be a second LAN hooked up to the firewall (for a total of 3 networks: two LANs and a WAN) or two firewalls (one between WAN and DMZ, one between DMZ and LAN).

Comment: If you are willing to set up another computer, you could drop an Ubuntu build out there with two NICs in it and use `ufw` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW. It uses `iptables` and is very customizable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables

Comment: Cool, thanks for the suggestion!  That might be something to look into for future projects :)

Comment: watch [techsnap show 101](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/33641/gif-me-root-techsnap-101/) and fast forward to user feedback near the end. They explain how firewalls are useless in this case and how pfsense is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put machine C into its own network range. It is the best way to isolte the machine and protect your other machines that live on thier own IP range. The only problem is that you might **need an extra router** with DHCP and WAN port or a switch that support NAT. Possibly manually configuring PC C will also work. Essentially creating two networks.

[image]

### Your main network <sup>(default out of box)</sup>

- WAN IP: Pulbic IP from ISP
- IP LAN: 192.168.0.254 (routers IP)
- DHCP : 192.168.0.254 (192.168.0.y - 192.168.0.z)
- GATEWAY: 192.168.0.254

### Your protected network <sup>(tweaked)</sup>

- WAN IP - 192.168.**0**.x (From DHCP Second router)
- IP LAN - 192.168.**1**.254
- DHCP: 192.168.**1**.254 (192.168.**1**.y  - 192.168.**1**.z)<sup>(for 2nd network)</sup>
- GATEWAY: 192.168.**0**.254 (Route to Internet only)

### Manual

In your [E4200 Manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Cisco/E4200/Manual/242917) on page 9 there is a section about advanced routing. This might be a solution or method to help you create separate networks. Ideally, newer routers offer Virtual Networks and things like that help you manage this better.

### Alternatives

This is advance- but it is one of the preferred one for all good sysadmins!

You can replace your current router with an advanced [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) compatible router or PC. It can(and should) completely replace the router from your ISP. You need to look at the compatibility list and select a router of your liking. It requires you to install pfsense to it which is FreeBSD. The info says it for use as a firewall and router. Router is what you are interested in. But it does a whole lot more!

You can install proxies, squid, throttling, dns, etc. pfSense allows you to create as many networks and you can configure them how ever you like!

[image]

---

Using firewalls on the computers them self is not the resolution to the problem. I t can give you a false sense of security but firewalls are designed to protect incoming connections to a given computer. Blocking standard ports will cause unexpected long term complications for things that were designed to make life easier!

---

--Edit added after answer accepted.

Some external reference where [2 sysdamins on Techsnap 101](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/33641/gif-me-root-techsnap-101/) agree that firewalls are not the answer in protecting computer from each other. Fast-forward to the end bit. Also how to isolate a machine from the network using a VLAN, NIC or Routes for the very exact question you asked here

Comment: That won't work, unless you manually adjust routing rules on the PC. The PC needs to know how to reach the gateway, and the only things it knows how to reach by default are the machines on its subnet.

Comment: Yes I said that- He might need another switch or router. You just being spiteful now. This is the industry standard for Isolating computers on a network. Trying to get some homebrewed hackish methods is really bad advise.

Comment: Industry standard is to use one or two dedicated firewalls. It's not _just_ to change the IP range. With a second _router_ (a switch will not work), this would work, but you need to configure that router's firewall to make it actually keep C off your standard network. Unless you have a firewall between C and A/B, they aren't isolated.

Comment: So Virtual Netorks are a waste of time then? Tell that to CISCO which specifically created such netowrks to help ISOLATE computers on the same NETWORK. Not firewalls. Your concept is completly messed up. He is not trying to protect the PC's from WAN attacks but ISOLATE! Bleeding heck

Comment: Computers on different VLANs are on different networks (sorta). You need a level 3 switch or a router to connect them. VLANs can prevent sniffing, but since they need to be connected in the end, a VLAN by itself doesn't stop C from accessing A/B. You need something to go between those networks - a firewall. You seem confused by what a firewall is - I'm talking about things like `pf`, which go between _networks_, not something designed to protect just the computer it's installed on.

Comment: Look- End of the day firewalls is not the correct answer for long term and security reliability. Like I said already several times the OP will need another device- Did I not? I did, I did... *face palm*

Comment: It sounds like to ensure a secure isolation, I need an additional router in between the two networks.

Comment: Hi ppumkin, for the above diagram, would the configuration be set up to allow traffic from the second router to the first, but not allow it if the destination was Machine A or Machine B?

Edit - The pf suggestion from cpast and ppumpkin is something that is worth looking into, thanks!

Comment: Using the 2 routers - the second one needs to be one like a internet router. You the cable into 2nd router WAN port and into 1st router LAN. Because they are on different IP's neither network will be able to cross talk. There is no special configuration! 1st router will see 2nd router as a "PC" but all the PC's on router 1 cannot see the other network because you have to set it up to use another IP address. It is a bit strange but it does work! I have done it many times- especially when there are 2 or more Internet connection.

Comment: Ah I see now, that makes sense.  The clients from the first router have no visibility into anything connected to the second router.  Still, I'm a little worried that traffic still has to pass from the second router back to the first, could it be guaranteed there's no way of the traffic being routed to one of the first router's hosts?

Comment: The only way is if a user on Machine C accesses the 2nd router and changes all the settings so he is on the same IP range as the 1st router. But neither side can scan other ranges without proper hacking or changing settings in the routers. Take a look at pfsense. It might seem daunting and complciated. But it gives you SOOOO much flexibilty in how you want to exactly setup networks. Plus there are so many security things you can do to help prevent malicious activity. It is a router and firewall tightly combined to give you maximum security and configuration.

Comment: A firewall is the correct method to use. It is a second device. `pf`, which is the part of pfSense that isolates networks, _is_ a firewall.

Comment: That said, with the answer how it is now, I'm un-downvoting.

Comment: I think there was some confusion for ppumkin around what was meant by firewalls.  We all meant the same thing, but just needed to clarify that we were purely talking about physical hardware for the firewalls and not something like Windows Firewall.

I liked Rich's answer too as it was essentially a similar suggestion, but there's a good level of detail and discussion here so I've selected it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that came to my mind is a firewall.

You could make firewall rules on Machine C that don't allow any TCP connections to or from 192.168.x.x (or whatever your local LAN is configured to use) but allow other outgoing connections. You would need to specifically allow connections to your router though. Of course you'd need to be able to lock down this configuration so that no one can change the firewall rules.

In this case you can also change the firewalls on Machines A and B to not initiate/receive any packets from Machine C as well.

I'm not good at ASCII art but you could also pick up another router. Call your current router R1, and your network is 192.168.1.x. Pick up R2, make it a client of R1, and machine C a client of R2, by itself, with network 192.168.2.x. (Machines A and B are still on R1, 192.168.1.x). Play with the firewall on R2, allowing 192.168.2.1, but rejecting anything else 192.168.x.x. This should cost you about USD$50 or so, plus some time. You essentially create your own DMZ. Machine C is now Double-NATted, which may be good or bad, depending on what it's doing. If it's a server, you now have to allow connections from the Internet through R1 and R2.  Firewalls on Machine A and B would be set for 192.168.2.x. You can still firewall Machine C, but then you still have the hardware firewall on R2 if it gets compromised.

**BTW:** Replacing the stock firmware on an E4200 may be good for other reasons. Some firmware versions allowed Cisco to "cloud manage" it. Also, Im not sure if you can turn off WPS (which has been broken) through the stock firmware. If you do this, can you comment and let me know how this works? My uncle has an E4200 I was going to reflash in my infinite free time.

Comment: That's one of my main concerns, I'd need to be able to restrict a compromised Machine C from changing that rule.

Comment: Firewall rules would be the best way to deal with this.

Comment: I'm not sure if my E4200 allows creating different subnets and I'm not currently at home so I can't check, but do you think having Machine C in a separate subnet and having firewall rules would do the trick?  Machine C will be a desktop PC so we don't have to worry about re-configuring the rules, thankfully.

Comment: If Machine C is compromised, aren't all firewall rules on machine C at risk? I don't see how you can rely on a security feature on a compromised machine.

Comment: -1 Firewalls are used to block unauthorised access. Not isolate machines!

Comment: My hope is that there's a way to stop Machine C from being able to administer the router.

EDIT - Wouldn't a firewall rule that blacklists all traffic be equivalent to isolation, though?

Comment: @ppumkin Not quite - Firewalls absolutely can isolate machines. Windows Firewall-type firewalls can isolate a computer from the outside world, but not the outside world from the computer. However, that's not the only kind of firewall - network-level firewalls are designed to control what traffic passes between networks (a network firewall is connected to several networks using multiple NICs), and that is _exactly_ what he wants.

Comment: That's correct, cpast, I'm thinking along the lines of a network-level firewall.  I'm not sure if my poor home router can split into 2 subnets and blacklist all traffic from the subnet Machine A and Machine B reside on, but I think that would be a solution as long as Machine C can't administer the router.

Comment: No ways! firewalls are used to protect a SINGLE computer and not ISOLATE a computer from a network. I use firewalls to allow IP's to connect to my Database and firewalls to Block botnets. But all local computers are trusted and firewalls do not really help.

Comment: @ppumkin: That is just incorrect. Network firewalls go in between two networks, and regulate what traffic can flow between them. They aren't software you put on your main computer; they're either hardware devices, or software you put on a separate computer that generally does little more than router+firewall.

Comment: Yes! TWO NETWORKS! Not the same network like the OP is trying todo. My answers shows how to do this- And I DID say he needs extra bits. How is your answer creating 2 Networks?

Comment: @ppumkin This isn't my answer; I didn't post an answer (though I'm considering it). Establishing a second network means putting a router in between. You can't connect networks without a router. If you are using home equipment, you'll need 2 routers (home routers can't connect 3 networks, just 2), and you need to configure the router firewalls.

Comment: Is that not what I said in my answer? You need another router/swithc that will translate network traffic to the gateway! Besides I re read this terribly unformatted and cluttered answer and that is the same thing Rich is saying. What are you even on about cpast? Firewalls IS NOT THE WAY TO GO.

Comment: I withdraw my -1 just because I misread the answer. Really @11k rep you would have thought you knew how to format an answer nicely. You deserve -1 just for that.

Comment: From the sound of things, I will likely need an additional router to securely isolate Machine C.

Comment: Although I have selected ppumkin's answer as the correct one, Rich, your suggestion is similar and also valid.  There's a good level of detail/discussion in the other answer, however, which could be useful for review to other visitors, so I've selected it as the answer for this question.  Your answer has also been upvoted, though, and I thank you for your assistance!  I'll let you know if I get around to flashing the E4200, although it may be some time before I am able to get around to it.