# Isolate one computer on the LAN from all other computers on the LAN

Tags: windows, networking, lan, dmz

I would like to know how I can best and most readily set up a single PC on my network such that it cannot see any of the others PCs or access any of their resources. The PC must still be able to access the Internet.

I want it to behave like Windows Network Discovery is turned off. However, the user should not be able to override this setting (the use will be an admin on the isolated PC). Maybe there is a way to use Group Policy to do this?

DMZ seems too risky and VLANs may be too complicated for what we are trying to do.  I also looked at Windows Firewall rules but couldn't come up with one that seemed to work.

Simple isolation is fine.  We don't expect the user on the isolated PC to be trying to hack their way into the network.  We just want it to be such that they don't stumble in there by accident.

Any suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Disable: Sever, Workstation, and Computer Browser, in Services.

Comment: On my opinion, a VLAN Is simpler in the long run. The fact that it is hardware enforced makes software configuration unnecessary. You do need the right equipment and skills. Ad an alternative, many consumer Wifi routers have the option to configure “guest” SSiDs that prohibit access to the rest of the network and only allow internet access.

Comment: You mean blocking only "incoming" traffic to that PC or outgoing (except internet) "traffic" from that PC as well?

Comment: Moab, what are the full consequences of disabling those three services?  Can a user still access the computer via RDP?  Would the Internet access be affected?

Comment: Albin.  We want it to be configured such that the users on the isolated PC cannot access resources on the rest of the PCs.  It is a privacy issue more than anything else.  We have a client who has placed a PC in our office because we are creating specialized and complicated data for them.  They will RDP to this machine to access the software and data.  We simply want to keep our network resources private from that machine as they contain data etc that belongs to other clients.  They should be able to do just about anything they need on that machine except browse and access network resources.

Comment: Guest wifi with LAN port disabled is the easiest option. Otherwise, you may consider blocking everything but port 80 and 443. should also make other network stuff inaccessible

Comment: VLAN, or different subnets with no route between them in the firewall.

Comment: @Gork what kind of router/firewall/switch are you using?

Comment: @Albin. We have a Netgear XS748T Managed Switch and a Linksys EA9500V2 Router.  I am very new hear and this has been given to me as a priority.  Our network is very simple, no domain, modest network hardware as you can see.  I am looking into a better firewall but was also looking for solutions that worked with what we have.  They may even turn out to be temporary while we decide on better hardware and get it into place.

Comment: Can you add links to the specs of the devices?

Comment: @Albin
https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=263808.
https://www.netgear.com/images/datasheet/switches/SmartSwitches/XS708T_XS712Tv2_XS716T_XS728T_XS748T_DS.pdf

Comment: It supports guest Wi-Fi (up to 5 clients and 2 networks) so at least that will work. But it seem to only support a WLAN guest network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to restrict network access for one machine on a home LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/568388/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-network-access-for-one-machine-on-a-home-lan)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart.  This is an option for sure.  I have been looking for advice on the alternatives and this thread has given me some great feedback.  Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For "dependable isolation" you will have to use VLAN (for separation) and a Firewall (to "reconnect" to the shared internet router but to only let the internet traffic pass).
2. You could block the outgoing traffic to the network via the Windows firewall ([see here](https://superuser.com/a/568397/201818)) but this is not very secure since the firewall is on the client itself an can be disabled or simply or passed over (e.g by using a different client on that network port).
3. Other then that you existing router/firewall/switch device might have a build in option to separate the client from the rest of the network, but that depends on what devices you are actually using and how you network is set up.
4. Using a separate Router [see here](https://superuser.com/a/568415/201818) should work as well (depending on the router, a few thins need to be set up correctly so client will only be able to access internet and not the LAN through the 2nd router):

   `Switch <---> 2nd Router, NAT enabled <---> PC`

Note: LPChip is right, "Guest wifi with LAN port disabled" is the easiest option. I'll let him post an answer for that if he wants to.

Note2: Guest network seems only to be supported via WLAN. So for wired Ethernet you'll need to use on of the other solutions.

Comment: I am starting to get some good idea of what will be involved.  Wifi has not been my first choice because of inconsistent performance, occasional dropped connections etc.  Thanks for the help and suggestions so far.  They really do help clarify my best options.

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Gork Might be a good idea to troubleshoot the Wi-Fi (unless it's a distance issue or similar)

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer.  I have gotten some good ideas and some reinforcement of what I was already looking into.  I will have to do some more work to get to my final solution but I am much better informed now.  Thanks to all for your assistance.