# How to best isolate computer in public LAN

Tags: networking, router, security, lan

I need to use a shared LAN with other people I don't know, which I can't control and about which I know nothing about. That means I can't change settings in the router and I don't know how isolated will my PC be from the rest.

I was wondering what the best option would be to secure myself and I came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/568388), which suggest using two routers to isolate devices on a network. My question is:

Will using another router work in my case? That is, can i use another router without access to the main one?

If not, do I have any other options? I know not using the network at all would be great, but it is not an option unfortunately.

If yes, what should I look for in a router to buy?

PS: I use Windows 10 and both connections (router to LAN and router to PC) would be wired (Ethernet cable).

Edit: I have learnt I will not need to identify myself to use the network

Comment: The thing you have not explained is *why*. Do you work for the FBI? Are they all hackers who want nothing more than to read the files on your computer? Why don't these hackers/FBI agents just steal your computer? If you disable [file sharing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf) in Windows, what other risks do you think there are?

Comment: You should trust the Windows firewall, which by default does not allow connections from the outside.

Comment: @Gantendo No, I do not work for the FBI, but [worms are a real thing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34343), and possibility that one of the other ~100 people in the LAN accidentally downloads something sketchy, and that sketchy thing happens to have a zero-day on one of the lots of (legitimate, but not bulletproof) pieces of software that I use is a real one (at least I think so, see the linked question). And I really can't afford the downtime that that would mean.

Comment: @harrymc I know, but a lot of apps I use (Skype, Discord, etc...) usually ask for firewall bypass. Would I lose functionality? Also, I do plan on using Windows Firewall, I just asked this question to confirm what is said in the [linked post](https://superuser.com/questions/568388) will work for me (which I think it will, but I post this for somebody more knowledgeable than me to check).

Comment: These application ask for firewall bypass for communicating from the inside to the outside, meaning outgoing rules, not incoming rules. These application outgoing rules are superfluous in the default setup, because by default every inside app can communicate freely with the outside. They are just in case that your firewall setup is much more restrictive than the default.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will however keep the question up because of my other concerns.

Comment: To the rest of your question, yes you can use a second router, and any router would be fine. Some routers notice they're set up on an internal network and go into "bridge" mode (which just merges networks together), so you may need to adjust the default settings

Comment: @harrymc "These application ask for firewall bypass for communicating from the inside to the outside, meaning outgoing rules, not incoming rules." This is not correct. All these dialogs are exclusively about inbound rules.

Comment: The comments suggesting that OP just fly with the Windows firewall are missing the point. OP is asking about connecting a personal machine to a large, untrusted network. Do you know what else is a large, untrusted network? The internet. Which of you commenters will be the first to jack your Windows PC directly onto the internet? Anyone? Hello?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thank you very much. Could you maybe post an answer with some more details on how to configure the router so as not to act as a bridge?

Comment: @DanielB Looking at my firewall rules it does indeed seem like I have inbound rules created by certain apps (mainly communication programs and videogames) to (I guess) allow them to function. It would be a painful process (or even maybe an impossible one, as I need some of the apps) to revert all of them.

Comment: Video games and torrent software etc are an exception, but having an open port does not mean a vulnerability. An open port is useless if no program is listening on it. And when a listener exists, the port is as secure as is that listener (meaning if it has known or unknown points of attack). Run-time antivirus protection and good backups are recommended in such an environment, including some careful judgement of the installed products.

Comment: @harrymc Again, yes, probably it will be fine, but, thankfully, I can afford a simple router, and I think that everybody knows that a firewall at the router level is better than the Windows firewall (and yes, I know there are options after that, but, the ones I have thought about are not practical). My question is (mainly) about configuring the router. I asked for alternatives _only in the case the using the router was impossible or it didn't grant any benefits_.

Comment: Use a router, but you don't need to lug a large normal router around - use a Raspberry Pi/other equivalent, and run [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) on it, and it can either be powered by the laptop or power bank

Comment: Just to remark that many of these products use UPnP Port Forwarding to themselves open their own ports in the router.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the reminder. I have (and will continue to have) UPnP turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a NAT router to shield yourself, as described in the linked question. (This or may not be frowned upon by the network operators, not that they can reliably detect it.)

But you don’t need to. I feel that the built-in firewall in Windows is enough. You simply need to scrutinize requests for inbound exceptions a little more. You don’t have to grant them. Simply press cancel. The program will still work. The dialog will not pop up again. Revoking existing exceptions is a bit of a pain, but you only have to do it once.

Keep in mind that Windows supports two firewall profiles: One for private networks (you wouldn’t use that) and one for public networks (the one you want). You can see which network adapter is using which in *Windows Defender Firewall*. To switch the profile, you’ll have to navigate the modern Settings app.

There’s also another possibility with the Windows firewall: You can set it (per profile) to disregard any exceptions. You can do this from *Windows Defender Firewall*, where the option is under *Change notification settings*. This would allow you to leave the existing exceptions as-is.

Comment: Thank you. And I understand that using the Wi-Fi from my own router (connected but isolated to the public network) would be much better than connecting Android devices to the public Wi-Fi directly (everyone nowadays is talking about not using public Wi-Fi). The reason I had left Android devices out of the original question is because I can leave them disconnected altogether from the public network, using cell data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148345/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-jw0914).