# Create private WiFi network on shared apartment network - being blocked somehow?

Tags: networking, router, internet, dd-wrt

I'm trying to set up my own private WiFi network using my apartment building's shared network. I have access to the shared network via WiFi (WPA2-Personal normal password authentication) and ethernet. I obviously don't have the admin access to configure any settings on this shared network myself, and the apartment staff don't have an interest in helping to set anything up.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have some smart-home stuff, some mqtt stuff, and a few other DIY devices and microcontrollers, that are difficult (or potentially impossible) to set up without being able to assign static IP addresses. The devices need to be able to communicate with each other over the local network, and several of them need to be connected to the internet.

I tried setting up a router (LAN from wall -> WAN on router) as has been answered on other questions on this site. However, I ran into some issues, and I was hoping someone who's a bit more knowledgeable could point me in the right direction in terms of debugging.

What I've tried so far:

- Router (Linksys E1500, DD-WRT firmware): My understanding is that in general, by connecting the LAN port from my wall (presumably from some router/switch in the apartment building) to the WAN port on a router, I can create a new private network. However, I wasn't able to get this to work. Devices were able to connect to the network, but were not able to connect to the internet. I even tried setting up OpenVPN on the router, but still devices were not able to connect to the internet. It's entirely possible I'm just configuring the router incorrectly, since I'm not very experienced with networking and this is a weird use-case, so I moved on to other methods to try and debug.
- Linux Wifi Hotspot: I used [this project](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot) to create a WiFi hotspot in Linux (ubuntu-server 22). Again, devices could connect to the network, and could for example ping the computer running the hotspot, but they were not able to connect to the internet. I also tried this through a VPN (sharing internet from the NordVPN "nordlynx" network interface), but still no internet. Throughout the process, the computer running the hotspot was able to connect to the internet fine. I was very surprised that it didn't work through the VPN, since I would have thought that it doesn't matter how my apartment network is configured if all the traffic is tunneling encrypted to the VPN server; they shouldn't be able to distinguish between traffic from the device running the hotspot (which worked) and traffic from the devices connected to its hotspot (which didn't work).
- Windows 11 "mobile hotspot": This one was just to test, I don't intend on using a Windows mobile hotspot as a permanent solution. Again, devices could connect to the network, and Windows would show e.g "1/8 devices connected", but the devices couldn't connect to the internet. The Windows 11 laptop was able to connect to the internet fine while this was going on. Connecting the Windows 11 laptop to a VPN did not affect anything. Since the Windows mobile hotspot works fine on other networks, and is designed to work without any special user configuration, I can definitely conclude that this isn't just user error on my part; something is definitely stopping these hotspots from working on my apartment network, either intentionally or unintentionally.

I tried a few things to try and see if it's just a DNS issue or a broader issue. For example, I tried pinging google.com, and I also tried pinging an ip address of google (looked up using a device connected to a working network); neither worked. But I'm not very knowledgeable about networking, so I'm not sure what else to do.

So I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to help me debug and figure out a) how the apartment network is blocking these connections (what is actually going wrong in the process of connecting), and b) how to get around it.

Comment: WPA2-Personal does not use usernames. If your apartment building's Wi-Fi network requires usernames then it is not WPA2-Personal. It might be WPA2-Enterprise, or it might have some kind of "captive portal" situation going on but it's not just WPA2-Personal. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, have you plugged a PC directly into the Ethernet port in the wall, disabled the Wi-Fi card in that PC just to be sure, and successfully accessed the internet from that PC as a simple endpoint PC, not as a router? That's something you need to get working first, before you start trying to make it act as a router or replace it with a dedicated router box.

Comment: Once you have connected the PC and verified the internet connection, go into the router and set there exactly the same connection settings as you used in the PC.

Comment: @Spiff Apologies, it's just a password, no username

Comment: In the cases where I tried to use a Linux laptop or a Windows 11 laptop as a router/hotspot, the laptop itself was able to connect to the internet fine (through the ethernet connection, with all other network interfaces disabled). It's only the devices connected to the hotspot that don't have internet connection

Comment: Get a packet capture of whatever is happening on the Linux laptop's uplink interface: are packets from the laptop itself, compared to packets forwarded from other hosts, being sent to the same destination (dst MAC)? Can you try configuring iptables on the router to override IP TTL?

Comment: Make sure that the gateway is correctly set to point to that of the apartment router. Then, your router's IP address should be the one given to it by your apartment's DHCP server, but, your router's DHCP server **must** be set on another subnet. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/568388) for details.

Comment: It does appear to be a TTL issue. The ping's from the connected devices are returning "ICMP time exceeded in-transit". I'll try setting the router to increase TTL and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It was a TTL issue; it seems that the apartment is setting TTL of incoming packets to 1 to prevent other routers from being added. I saved the following line into my DD-WRT startup script, and now internet connectivity works:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i vlan2 -j TTL --ttl-inc 10
```

For anyone finding this answer, `vlan2` may be different on different routers. It needs to be the name of the WAN interface. (Also, `--ttl-inc 1` would probably work, but it was 10 in the guide I found, and I left it just in case I end up doing something weird with the network)